# Text search not working with sunspot rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sunspot

I'm currently implementing a basic search bar with sunspot. My code seems to work but the search result always returns no object. I don't understand why and after reading all the sunspot documentation, I'm a bit lost. If anyone can just give me a clue, it could be very helpful.
Here is my code :

My controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @search = Book.search do
      fulltext(params[:search])
    end
    @books = @search.results  
   respond_with(@books)
  end
# ADDITIONAL CODE
end
```

My model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishs
  has_many :loans

  validates_presence_of :title, :author, :description

  enum status: [ :available, :unavailable, :on_loan ]

  searchable do
    string :title
    string :author
    string :description
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Listing books</h1>

    <%= form_tag books_path, :method => :get do %>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
            </span>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Title, description, author ..." %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <table class="table table-hover" style="margin-top: 20px">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- NAME OF COLUMN -->
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <% @books.each do |book| %>
        <!-- DO SOME STUFF -->
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `string` use `text` so it will be a full-text search. In your model try:

```
searchable do
  text :title
  text :author
  text :description
end
```

If that syntax fails, this will work

```
searchable do
  text :title, :author, :description
end
```

In the end, a reindex looks to have fixed it: `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

Comment: I already tried that and the behavior is exactly the same. I still have no results.

Comment: Hmm. Did you verify the solr server is running?   `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start` and maybe try a reindex: `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex`.

Comment: I think I'm becoming mad. I did it at least 10 times and it didn't work. After your comment I tried to reindex again and now it works ... Thanks for your help.